# Computation of the logarithmic absolute Weil height of the $\sqrt[3]{2}$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Each algebraic number of this infinite sequence
\begin{equation} 
2, \: \sqrt{2},\:\sqrt[3]{2},\:\sqrt[4]{2},…,\sqrt[n]{2},…
\end{equation}
have bounded height.
I would like to compute the absolute logarithmic Weil height $h(\alpha)$ of the algebraic number, say: $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ for example.
Do I have to compute first the absolute Weil height $H$:
\begin{equation}
H(\alpha)=\big(\vert x_0 \vert \prod_{\vert \alpha_i \vert > 1} \vert \alpha_i \vert \big)^{1/d}
\end{equation}
where $x_0$ is the leading nonzero coefficient of the degree $d$ minimal polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of $\alpha$ and $\alpha_i$ are the conjugates of $\alpha$.

I saw more abstract definitions of the absolute Weil height like:
\begin{equation}
H: \: \overline{\mathbb{Q}} \longrightarrow [1,\infty)\\
H(\alpha):=\prod_v \max\{1,\vert \alpha \vert_v \} \: \: \alpha \in k
\end{equation}
where the product is over all places $v$ of the algebraic number field $k$ that contains the algebraic number $\alpha$. Do they say the same thing ?
I don’t know how to use those definitions (even the simpler one) in order to compute $h(\alpha)=\log H(\alpha), \: \alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$.
Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks.

About the algebraic number $\alpha$: his minimal polynomial is $x^3-2$, the roots are $e^{\frac{1}{3}2i\pi}\sqrt[3]{2}$, $e^{\frac{2}{3}2i\pi}\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$.
The number field is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2 \rangle$ of degree $3$ over the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake by taking the absolute Weil height instead of:
$H(\alpha)=\vert x_0 \vert \prod_{\vert \alpha_i \vert > 1} \vert \alpha_i \vert$.
The cube roots of unity have absolute values $1$. So the absolute height is $H(\alpha)=\sqrt[3]{2}$. Very simple !
Then $h(\alpha)=\log H(\alpha) =\frac{1}{3}h(2)=\frac{1}{3}\log 2 \leq \log 2$.
Although the sequence of algebraic numbers have bounded height it doesn’t satisfy the Northcott property since it has unbounded degree.